# Register all tags ending with a postfix as inline-grid using Css or Js

Tags: javascript, css

I have some custom tags as follows:

```
<section>
    <section-wrap></section-wrap>
</section>
<form>
    <form-wrap></form-wrap>
</form>
```

... and so on. Imagine I add another custom tag of the same order such as `header-wrap`. I would require to register it again using web components. Css as far as I have read has no way of picking up tag names except by declaring them explicitly.

How can I declare the custom tags ending in `-wrap` as being `inline-grid` elements universally?

Comment: Are you using web components?

Comment: @metatron Nope. Just plain css and vanilla js.

Comment: So you aren't registering them, just using them?

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't clear. Would like to use web components to register them. Have done it one at a time but don't know of how to register them at once. This is something important since I have additional groups of custom tags that need same treatment. Will clarify the question.

Comment: Can't you just do it in JS - perhaps have an array of tags you'd like to create or something so it would only be a few lines of code. Alternatively if you don't register them, just plod through them one the DOM is loaded using JS to set the styling. Again only a few lines of code.

Comment: Doing one by one is possible in JS and if there is no way of registering them all at once, then will just have to go with css. With JS am considering registering and adding these tags automatically together. The easiest way would be for the w3c specification to declare the `parent-child` tag as an `inline` of the parent tag. But that would be a dream come true. However, I have many. Project am working on is large. Some end in `-wrap`, some in `-group`, etc. It's the reason for the question, to find a way to handle them easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could add classes to the elements. It is trivial to select the *-wrap classes then.

This setup is fairly simple and will keep working if the dom changes (e.g. elements are inserted).

```css
[class$=-wrap] {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <section-wrap class=section-wrap></section-wrap>
</section>
<form>
    <form-wrap class=form-wrap>
        <div>grid cell 1</div>
        <div>grid cell 2</div>
    </form-wrap>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you know about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Comment: Yes, if using web components, didn't think about that use case.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes I do. However that requires registering them one at a time. Since I have a  sizable number of custom tags all with similar declarations, I needed a means of making declaration that are similar to all of them at once, rather than growing a JS file.

Comment: @metatron Actually custom tags are legal as long as they have a hyphen in them. JS recognizes them with no problem. However, they have to have a display. In this case, I need them to all have `inline-grid`, using a since declaration or something similar.

Comment: You're right. I edited the proposed solution. Ididn't think about using custom tags without web components before as they are usually mentioned together (web components and custom tags that is) so I was assuming a classic html5 approach. My bad.

Comment: @metatron I've tried this before and it's high maintenance. I've even gone as far as actually using custom attributes to make it simpler to use and maintain. What I wanted was a means to add a new custom tag, say `nav-wrap` without thinking of registering another `-wrap` tag.

Comment: By registering, you mean registering via customElements.define() or applying css (e.g. display: inline-grid) via a style rule in a css file?